# Using Radgrid filter expression to query collection gives exception 'Expression Expected'

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, dynamic-linq

I am trying to query a collection using the filter expression from my radgrid. On the RadGrid I have the property of `EnableLinqExpressions = "false"`

However I get the exception `Expression Expected` when using the code:

```
results = results.Where(filterExpression);
```

At the moment the filter expression is in the format
`"(([SCRIPT_AGENT] = 'Jack Davies'))"`

How can I solve this issue?

When I enter the following it works:

```
results = results.Where("SCRIPT_AGENT == @0", "Jack Davies")
```

Is there anyway to use my current filter expression or is there someway to convert it into a usable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the filter expression of the rad grid I decided to use a different approach and use the current data in the rad grid itself when a filter is applied:

```
        // If there is a filter applied then enter the loop if there isn't then the filter expression will be empty 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterExpression))
        {                
            // Create a new list of strings to hold the sequence ids
            List<string> sequenceIds = new List<string>();

            // For each row in the radgrid...
            foreach (GridDataItem row in rgCallRecordings.Items) // loops through each rows in RadGrid
            {
                // ...Add the sequence id to the list
                sequenceIds.Add(row.GetDataKeyValue("SEQUENCE_ID").ToString());                    
            }
            // Only return results whose sequence ids are in the list
            results = results.Where(a => sequenceIds.Contains(a.SEQUENCE_ID));                
        }
```

This eliminated the error and produced the same results as using the filter expressions.